# Bootstrap 5 toggable tab not working in nunjucks template

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, nunjucks

I am simply following the bootstrap documentation for tabs in this link
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navs-tabs/#tabs

From the documentation, I copied the sample implementation and implement it to my code like this

```
    ---
title: Portfolio
description: Portfolio
---

{% extends "./layouts/layout.njk" %}

{% block scripts %}{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

  <div class="demo py-5">
    <h2 class="my-5">Choose One of Our Demos</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="disabled-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#disabled-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="disabled-tab-pane" aria-selected="false" disabled>Disabled</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab" tabindex="0">A</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab" tabindex="0">B</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab" tabindex="0">C</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="disabled-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="disabled-tab" tabindex="0">D</div>
    </div>
 
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

It's being displayed properly but seems like nothing is happening when I click the tabs. It won't switch and display the correct content. It always just display "A" since that is the active tab set initially.

[image]

I am really not sure what I'm missing here. Bootstrap 5 is definitely installed. I'm thinking though does this something to do with nunjucks? Do I need to put a script somewhere, I'm also not sure where javascript codes should be put, when using nunjucks. Thanks of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above works as expected **IF** you include Bootstrap CSS and JS correctly. I guess the problem is that you didn't include Bootstrap JS or you did, but not properly.

See the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="demo py-5">
  <h2 class="my-5">Choose One of Our Demos</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link" id="disabled-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#disabled-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="disabled-tab-pane" aria-selected="false" disabled>Disabled</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab" tabindex="0">A</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab" tabindex="0">B</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab" tabindex="0">C</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="disabled-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="disabled-tab" tabindex="0">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right. I forgot to import the script tags
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js